# How to save attachment in MAPIFolder

Tags: vba, outlook

I would like to save an attached file in a mapi folder (Enterptise connect) when the mail arrives according to the subject's title.
The vba code I use allows me to move the messages to the destination folder.
Do you have any idea how to copy an attachment to a folder in a storage space like Enterprise connect?

```
Option Explicit Sub PseudoArchive() Dim objNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace Dim sourceFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder Dim destinationFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder Dim Items As Outlook.Items Dim Item As Object Dim Msg As String Dim i As Long

Set objNamespace = GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set sourceFolder = objNamespace.Folders("test1_1@Outlook.com").Folders("MyFodes")
Set destinationFolder = objNamespace.Folders("Interprise Connect").Folders("Test2").Folders("Save_Attachments")
Set Items = sourceFolder.Items

'Move emails in sourceFolder to destinationFolder
Msg = Items.Count & " Items in " & sourceFolder.Name & ", Move?"

If MsgBox(Msg, vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
    For i = Items.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set Item = Items.Item(i)
        DoEvents
        Item.Move destinationFolder
    Next
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Outlook folders do not contain files, they contain items such as MailItem or ContactItem. Are you trying to create a DocumentItem in an Outlook folder (DocumentItem  is crated when you drag a file from Windows Explorer to Outlook)?

Comment: This code move all messages in the destination folder. I need to move juste attachment if the message contains certains words.

Comment: One again, you cannot move just an attachment - you can save it as a file using Attachment.SaveAsFile, but an attachment cannot be saved into an Outlook folder (unless you use DocumentItem), only to the file system.